# WebStorm error: Unable to find application named 'http://www.google.com'

Tags: intellij-idea, browser, webstorm

I just downloaded WebStorm and looking at my site using the browser tool is giving me the error of 'Unable to find application named http://www.google.com'

How do I rectify this issue?

Comment: Hmm?.. Could you please post a screenshot and describe what you did to get there.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/D2nlu

Comment: So ... what do you do/press/click to get this screen? What will happen if you click on "Fix" ? I could not find existing tickets on JB Issue Tracker with such message... Could this be your Proxy settings? Need details.

Comment: when I click "fix" it takes me to the preferences box and I am supposed to plug in the URL for the browser of choice.  When I do that and apply, nothing happens.  Can you please expand on proxy settings?

Comment: No ideas TBH.  Please try asking JetBrains Support Team directly -- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731

Comment: please provide screenshot of   preferences box you are taken to